# How to test dockerignore file?

Tags: docker, shell, node-modules, dockerignore

After reading the [`.dockerignore` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file), I'm wondering if there is a way to test it?

### Examples

```
**/node_modules/
```

How do I check my dockerfile ignore the correct files and directories?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One thing that the other answers do not consider, is that this will potentially copy many gigabytes of data and be very slow, when all you want to do is find out which file(s) you need to exclude to reduce the image size.

So here is how you test your `.dockerignore` without actually copying data:

```
$ rsync -avn . /dev/shm --exclude-from .dockerignore
```

What this will do, is try to sync your current directory with the empty in-memory folder `/dev/shm` verbosely and dry-run (don't actually copy anything) the `--exclude-from` option reads glob patterns in the same format as `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore`

You will end up with a list of files copied and a summary with the total size at the end:

```
file.bogus
tests/
tests/conftest.py
tests/test_model.py

sent 1,954 bytes  received 207 bytes  4,322.00 bytes/sec
total size is 209,916,337  speedup is 97,138.52 (DRY RUN)
```

Add it to `.dockerignore`:

```
*.bogus
```

and test again:

```
tests/
tests/conftest.py
tests/test_model.py

sent 1,925 bytes  received 204 bytes  4,258.00 bytes/sec
total size is 201,145  speedup is 94.48 (DRY RUN)
```

This is extremely fast and doesn't fill your disk.

Edit: There is one difference that I have found. For rsync the pattern `*.bogus` matches all files with that name regardless of the directory. `.dockerignore` however only matches `*.bogus` in the current directory. To get the same behavior you need to prefix the pattern with the path glob characters `**/*.bogus` This will still work with rsync.

Comment: This is the kind of elegant and fast solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You Sir, just made my day... with that brain of yours!

Comment: You can additionally add a `h` flag to rsync (like `rsync -avnh`) so that the output is more human readable.

Comment: I tried this but by `.dockerignore` excludes some files with `!/some/path`. They are effectively added to the container, but not shown with this solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @EmmanuelB looks like rsync treats the `!` character differently. you can test it by adding `--include=/some/path` to the rsync command line.

Comment: This answer was worth 5.43GB to me

Answer (score 169):

To expand on [VonC's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946786/802365), here's a sample build command you can use to create an image with the current folder's build context:

```
docker image build --no-cache -t build-context -f - . <<EOF
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /build-context
COPY . .
CMD find .
EOF
```

Once created, run the container and inspect the contents of the `/build-context` directory which includes everything not excluded by the `.dockerignore` file:

```
# run the default find command
docker container run --rm build-context

# or inspect it from a shell using
docker container run --rm -it build-context /bin/sh
```

You can then cleanup with:

```
docker image rm build-context
```

Comment: Use this CMD to find biggest folders: `CMD du -m $(find -type d .) | sort -rn | head`. Remove `-type d` if you want to check all files.

Answer (score 34):

To get a detailed analysis of the build context you could use [pwaller/docker-show-context](https://github.com/pwaller/docker-show-context).

```
$ go get -v -u github.com/pwaller/docker-show-context
$ cd ~/path/to/project/using/docker
$ docker-show-context
```

It outputs statistics about the build such as file sizes and upload times.

Comment: It never occurred to me to ignore the .DS_Store on Mac.  This is a cool command!

Comment: This looks promising, if that tool were compiling these days :(

Answer (score 24):

To expand on [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966234/516433)'s answer (which implements [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946786/516433)'s answer), you can do it with one simple command:

```sh
# no cache to ensure output
# progress plain in case you are using buildkit
docker build --no-cache --progress plain --file - . <<EOF
FROM busybox
COPY . /build-context
WORKDIR /build-context
RUN find .
EOF
```

Switching from `CMD` to `RUN` means you don't have to ever run the container as the build will output the result of the `find .`.

Answer (score 9):

To expand on [Lucas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196656/2397150) answer which expands on [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966234/516433)'s answer (which implements [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38946786/516433)'s answer), if you are using buildx you will also need to set the type of progress output by adding `--progress plain` and of course to not forget the `--no-cache`:

```sh
docker build --no-cache --progress plain -f - . <<EOF
FROM busybox
COPY . /build_context
WORKDIR /build_context
RUN find .
EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

One way is to make a small Dockerfile with an [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) or [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy) directive in it.

Try to add or copy a file in a `node_modules` folder: it is does not succeed, that would be because of the `.dockerignore`.

Comment: I tested with `ADD testfile .`, create file, add to .dockerignore, rebuild, it should error.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Lucas's answer (which implements BMitch's and VonC's answer), you get an easier to understand tree structure with:

```
$ docker build --no-cache --progress plain --file - . <<EOF
FROM debian
RUN  apt update && apt install tree -y
COPY . /build-context
RUN tree /build-context
EOF
```

which outputs:

```
#8 0.342 /build-context
#8 0.342 |-- dirA
#8 0.342 |   |-- a
#8 0.342 |   |-- b
#8 0.342 |   |   `-- lib
#8 0.342 |   |       |-- common
#8 0.342 |   |       |   |-- __init__.py
#8 0.342 |   |       |   |-- other.py
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solutions,, to add to @Sekenre's answer.

As he mentioned the `rsync` matches all files regardless of directory position on the `*.bogus` which means if you want to negate the .dockerignore file and ignore everything except for what you want to allow, which results in putting `*` at the top of the .dockerignore file, then the rsync method won't transfer any files at all,, even if you have a negated statement for a file just right below it, but a tool to check this would be amazing.

Even having a vscode extension for seeing the files that are ignored and allowed in the file browser would be amazing, just like the git and gitignore thing in vscode file explorer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32087320)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Sekenre answer, you can pass the flag --dry-run. Which will show what will be copied with out actually copying anything.

```
rsync -avn . /dev/shm --exclude-from .dockerignore --dry-run
```

Comment: The shorthand `-n` is equivalent to `--dry-run` which is already included.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Shameless self-promotion ahead**

TL;DR: https://dockerignore.vw.codes

I recently was involved in a project with a convoluted pipeline, and needed rapid prototyping to check the validity of a dockerignore file.  I decided to start working on a web utility to quickly be able to verify the output of a dockerignore file.

The secret sauce; validation runs against the **actual [pattern-matcher function](https://github.com/moby/patternmatcher/blob/main/patternmatcher.go#L216)**.  See [Docker's CLI implementation](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/b8d5454963fd52b4ab305e5a473223878b157f5b/cli/command/image/build/context.go#L89), and [here's proof](https://github.com/DiggidyDev/dockerignore-validator/blob/main/api/validate/index.go#L53) of its usage in my implementation.

It's currently fairly primitive, but I've got plenty of ideas in the pipeline (<s>pun intended</s>).  It currently supports:

- Public GitHub repo imports
- Manual inputs for dockerignore config file and file
- Programmatic validation via an API (`/api/validate` - [docs](https://github.com/DiggidyDev/dockerignore-validator?tab=readme-ov-file#apivalidate))

I'm planning on adding GitHub authentication for private repo access.

Here's a snippet:
[image: Dockerignore validator showing files to ignore]

[image: Dockerignore validator showing files to copy]