# What directory does a Docker build start in?

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile that has, amongst other directives, the following:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN cd /tmp && \
  # several lines downloading/installing packages from zips

...

ADD src/config.json /myapp/config.json

WORKDIR /myapp
```

This is intended to be run from the root of the application repository to build the docker container. The `RUN` command is placed early because it's getting the application dependencies and this logically should occur early in the process. (It is also chaining a bunch of commands together in order to keep the number of layers low.) However, the `ADD` command expects to be in the same location as the Dockerfile - the root of the repository.

Given that, is there a way to 'remember' where the docker build started from, and use this to orient the `ADD`? (Specifically, running this in a local dev environment will have a different `whereami` when building than my build server.) Or am I stuck with interleaving these commands, first copying the configuration over, then downloading dependencies, and so on?

When I build, I am doing this from the root directory of my project (that contains a `src` folder):

```
docker build -t myapp:dev .
```

The error I get is:

> lstat src/config.json: no such file or directory

If I insert `RUN pwd` the docker build reports it as being `/`, but I don't know if this is what it considers it's 'context' (that is, any `ADD` commands are relative to the `pwd`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `docker build` command has one required parameter, a path to the context to send over to the docker engine for performing the build. This path is typically a single `.`, making the resulting command look like `docker build -t myimage:latest .`. All of the `ADD` and `COPY` commands pull in files from that context, in the above example, the current directory where you ran the `docker build` command would be used. For the server and each user that runs your `docker build` commands, they just need to pass the working directory that they have on their local machine.

The only other thing you can do to alter the `ADD` and `COPY` command behavior is to change the `WORKDIR` which defines the relative path for commands *inside* your container, but does not affect where files are pulled from the context you sent with your build command.

Comment: I'm very confused, then: `ADD` does not seem to find anything in the 'context' directory. (See updates to question.) The way you describe is what I expected, but something is going wrong. Is there a way to verify what docker sees as the context directory (or current workdir)?

Comment: Yes, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40966234/596285) for how to print out the current directory context.

Comment: Turns out this was a commenting issue, as I describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642784/dockerfile-build-yielding-lstat-error-on-add/41642977?noredirect=1#comment70485867_41642977) more clearly. I should have included the full actual line. Thanks for the lead on contexts!

Comment: Is it possible to highlight the last sentence of this answer? It clarifies what the Docker docs did not -- that `WORKDIR` only affects the context sent with `build`, inside the container. Thus, `WORKDIR /` does not pull in the root of your computer, but references the parent directory that is your context while building.