# Dockerfile build yielding lstat error on ADD

Tags: docker

I have a dead-simple project with the following structure:

```
docker/
|- src/
|  |- config.json
|
|- Dockerfile
```

The contents of the json file:

```
{
  "setting": "value"
}
```

The contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

ADD src/config.json /testapp/config.json  # Config
```

I run this build command:

```
docker build -t testapp:dev .
```

And get this result:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Step 1 : FROM python:3.5
 ---> 1d0326469b55
Step 2 : ADD src/config.json /testapp/config.json 
lstat testapp/config.json: no such file or directory
```

Why is this failing? Why is it that the not-found item is `testapp/config.json`? In the past I've used this exact construct to, for instance, copy `requirements.txt` files into temporary working directories. I don't understand what I'm missing about how `ADD` works that is causing this to fail. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Perhaps the "or directory" is to blame? Does the target directory exist?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think it will create the directory (at least I have another working dockerfile that seems to do that). If I add `RUN mkdir /testapp && ls -la /testapp` ahead of the `ADD` it fails with the same message, but creates and lists out the `testapp` directory.

Answer (score 3):

I fell victim to my IDE. This line will fail:

```
ADD src/config.json /testapp/config.json  # Config
```

But this will succeed:

```
ADD src/config.json /testapp/config.json
```

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) for add, it appears it's trying to use `Config` as the destination directory, and as such `/testapp/config.json` is treated as a source file. The IDE greyed out the `# Config`, making me think it was being treated as a comment: Dockerfiles do not do inline comments.

This is covered in Docker documentation on [comments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/format):

> Docker will treat lines that begin with # as a comment. A # marker anywhere else in the line will be treated as an argument.

Comment: Hah! Amazing how all of us just naturally disregard comments when reading things like that. I didn't notice that either.

Comment: @NickBurke Yeah, I feel a bit dim. Leaving the question up, though, in case it helps someone else.