# Docker build is not using cache

Tags: caching, docker, build

`docker build` is not using it's cache.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

generates the same output that this does:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --no-cache .
```

I am modifying the Dockerfile, adding commands at the end of the file. So the previous layers should be cached and valid.

I've got plenty of disk space.

Any ideas?

Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737

Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry:5000/base/python:xenial

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    less

COPY /etc/foo /etc/foo

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 75):

From your Dockerfile, if you append lines to your Dockerfile, or change the code being built, there's only one line that could be cached:

```
RUN mkdir /code
```

After that, you perform a:

```
COPY . /code
```

Since you have changed your Dockerfile, the contents of `.` have changed (the Dockerfile is part of `.`) and therefore the `COPY` needs to be performed again, generating a new layer. Once you generate a new layer, every following layer no longer has a cache and needs to be rebuild.

To improve caching, consider placing the lines that change less towards the top of your Dockerfile. That would leave the `COPY . /code` line at the very end of the file since it will change almost every time.

You should also include files you don't need in a `.dockerignore` file to avoid their changes breaking the cache. E.g. the `.dockerignore` could contain:

```
Dockerfile
.git
```

Or I tend to use an inverse file, ignore everything, and then reinclude the specific files I need to build my app:

```
*
!Makefile
!app/
```

The above would include only the `Makefile` and `app` directory when doing a `COPY . /code`, and everything else would be ignored.

Comment: I had the case where I used multiple scripts with the same name to build different docker images. With the ADD, the cached ignored that the file were different, thus only one image was really built. With the COPY, the last layer (the one consuming the script) is rebuilt, and all the docker images are built :). Thanks !

Comment: Note that you can include `Dockerfile` (and `.dockerignore`) in your .dockerignore file so it's excluded from `ADD` and `COPY` cache analysis. (You should still definitely order your Dockerfile by change order as recommended.)

Comment: Do I need to add .dockerignore to my .dockerignore file?

Comment: Yes, you can see for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946683/how-to-test-dockerignore-file

Comment: @ldg When I do this, Docker seems to ignore my Dockerfile altogether, meaning changes I make to it are not reflected at all when I run docker build.

Comment: I really wish there was some way to show or log why it was using the cache or not. I have gotten very adept at preventing caching when I need it to be prevented, but I often want it to cache for performance and I know nothing has changed in step that stops caching but it doesn't cache.

Comment: @nroose I recently added `regctl blob diff-layer` that may help you: https://github.com/regclient/regclient/pull/269