# Quarkus: Try to cache maven dependencies using multistage docker build

Tags: maven, docker, quarkus

I have got a simple Quarkus application and I try to build it using the following multistage Dockerfile.

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-slim AS build
WORKDIR /build
# Download Dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

# Build App
COPY src/ /build/src/
RUN mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -Dcheckstyle.skip

# Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jre-openj9 AS runtime
COPY --from=build /build/target/*-runner.jar /app/app.jar
COPY --from=build /build/target/lib/* /app/lib/

WORKDIR /app
RUN chgrp -R 0 /app &&\
    chmod g=u /app
USER 1001

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

and the pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>booking-mgr</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.10</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemProperties>
                    <native.image.path>
                      ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                    </native.image.path>
                  </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

The build works fine, it downloads the maven dependencies, then it creates the .jar and runs the .jar in the final container. But if I change something in the source code and leave the pom.xml untouched, the dependencies are downloaded again. It seems that `mvn dependency:go-offline` does not download all dependencies.

Is there a way to speed up docker builds that way? For example, I do the same with Spring Boot and everything works great there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which command did you run to build your image ?

Comment: using `docker build .` or in a docker-compose using`docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

Your pom.xml and src folder are in the build context (the dot in your command).
If you change files in src then you change your build context so you invalidate the COPY cache.

See [Docker build is not using cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929081/docker-build-is-not-using-cache)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I see in the docker build that a cached layer is used for the following step. 
`Step 4/14 : RUN mvn dependency:go-offline 
 ---> Using cache 
 ---> 6e9c65b87c29`
afterwards in the `package` step the dependencies are downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can split the Dockerfile into two, such as `builder-base.dockerfile` and `final.dockerfile`. Then, create a directory `builder-base` and move `pom.xml` into `builder-base`.

directory structure:

```sh
.
+-- builder-base
|   +-- pom.xml
|-- src
|-- builder-base.dockerfile
|-- final.dockerfile
```

In the `final.dockerfile` is :

```sh
FROM java-builder AS build

# Build App
COPY src/ /build/src/
RUN mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -Dcheckstyle.skip

# Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM adoptopenjdk:8-jre-openj9 AS runtime
COPY --from=build /build/target/*-runner.jar /app/app.jar
COPY --from=build /build/target/lib/* /app/lib/

WORKDIR /app
RUN chgrp -R 0 /app &&\
    chmod g=u /app
USER 1001

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

First, put this code into `builder-base.dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-slim 
WORKDIR /build
# Download Dependencies
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
```

So, at first, you should build a image named 'java-builder'

```sh
docker build -t java-builder -f builder.dockerfile ./builder-base
```

Now, you can compile the source code use the command below:

```sh
docker build -t app -f final.dockerfile .
```

The base image in the `final.dockerfile` is `java-builder`, if you don't re-build the image, you can always create the docker final image using the cache.

Comment: Have you tried that with quarkus? It is not working, so I don't think it is a problem with docker but has to do with maven dependency:go-offline. It seems that not all dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: Could you provide a demo that I can reproduce the problem ? After running `docker build -t java-builder -f builder.dockerfile ./builder-base`, the `java-build` image was built and all dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: just change something in the source code and run `docker build -t app -f final.dockerfile .` again, you will see that some dependencies are downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

I found `mvn package` will do the work.
Now I use:

```
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn --batch-mode \
        --quiet \
        --errors \
        dependency:go-offline \
        package

COPY src ./src
RUN mvn --batch-mode \
        --quiet \
        --errors \
        --define maven.test.skip=true \
        --define java.awt.headless=ture \
        clean package
```

Looks weird, but no errors.