# Making docker-compose use cache of multistage builds?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a multistage Dockerfile where the first stage is very compute intensive, so I want to make sure its cached.

I created a simple Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml to show what I mean.
Even if I re-build it several times, only the second stage is running from cache. The first stage is always re-building.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.4 as build-stage
RUN sleep 5
RUN touch /test

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
COPY --from=build-stage /test /test
```

#### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ./
      cache_from:
        - myservice:latest
        - myservice:build-stage
    image: myservice:latest
```

After doing `docker-compose build` here I can see the following images

```
REPOSITORY   TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myservice    latest        ae96394ac660   15 seconds ago   19.9MB
<none>       <none>        d4c212c2bcd1   15 seconds ago   936MB
node         15.4          6f7f341ab8b8   9 days ago       936MB
nginx        1.17-alpine   89ec9da68213   8 months ago     19.9MB
```

One could assume that the one called `<none>` is the `build-stage` image. But since it's not tagged I can't make the `cache_from` work.

If I had used only docker and not docker-compose I would do:
`docker build . --target build-image -t myservice:build-image`
This would build only the first stage and tag it so it can be used as cache afterwards. But is this possible with docker-compose?
I mean, there is a `target:` option in the docker-compose.yaml but if I add a separate service to build and tag only the first stage, that will also want to start when I do `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Details might be described in [Understanding cache_from in compose : docker](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/ffybys/understanding_cache_from_in_compose/).

Comment: Didn't find a solution to my example unfortuately

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45929081/docker-build-is-not-using-cache recommends adding a `.dockerignore` to prevent `docker` from sensing changes in `.` that is probably copied into the build-time container as part of the docker build as part of the docker-compose build.