# Is there a command to quickly check the effect of .dockerignore?

Tags: docker, dockerignore

Is there a command similar to `git status --ignored` for docker that shows the effect of the `.dockerignore` file?

For example git has:

```sh
$ git status --ignored
...
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    [bunch of files]
...
```

Is there a similar thing for docker?

Comment: I think the response to [How to test dockerignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946683/how-to-test-dockerignore-file) is a good option.

I would also install 'tree' inside the container and use 'tree -a' to better visualize the context.

Comment: @mihai If that's the best solution, that would be very disappointing. I was searching for a simple CLI-type command to quickly see what's currently ignored and what not.

Comment: :) this is not a polemic but I think you let yourself disappointed way too easily. If you follow the best practices then you wouldn't need this tool so much. I find it a very good practise to ignore everything and then only include what I want. It worked for me very well for years.

Comment: Hi @BastianVenthur the linked question has an updated answer that uses `rsync`. It's not a perfect match in file globbing syntax, but it's very fast and covers most use cases.