# Where to put .dockerignore?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

Consider the following typical `python` project structure:

```
fooproject 
  - main.py
  - src/
  - test/
  - logs/
  - Dockerfile
  - .dockerignore
  - README.md
```

The .dockerfile should prevent `test/` and `logs/` directories from being included in the docker image.

```
test/
logs/
```

Contents of `Dockerfile` are

```
FROM ubuntu16.04

COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app    
USER root    
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt    
ENTRYPOINT ["main.py"]
```

However, when running through PyCharm's automatic docker integration, the `test` and `logs` directories are both copied into the container.  The PyCharm run command ends up as follows:

```
7eb643d9785b:python -u /opt/project/main.py
```

I've tried a few things to no avail, such as making a duplicate copy of `.dockerignore` at the directory above the rest of the app.  For example:

```
COPY . /app/
COPY .dockerignore .dockerignore
WORKDIR /app
```

Wondering if it's possible that PyCharm's `/opt/project` is somehow interfering?  So **where exactly should .dockerignore be in a project like this?**

### Update

I shared the output of `docker container inspect` with BMitch, and he was able to find the solution.   PyCharm was automatically mounting a volume in the container settings run config

[image]

Comment: If you have /logs in the dockerignore replace it with logs or logs/

Comment: Thanks but I have it as `logs/` already

Comment: Are they included in the built image, or only available via a volume? Include `docker container inspect` output for your container id/name.

Comment: @BMitch thanks - so I did run this command but am hesitant to post on SO as it may contain sensitive info.  What specifically am I looking for?  I can PM it to you if you prefer

Comment: Recreate the problem in a non-sensitive environment and post the whole thing. Any IP addresses are non-routeable/internal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `.dockerignore` is used to control what files are included in the build context. This impacts the `COPY` and `ADD` commands in the Dockerfile, and ultimately the resulting image. When you run that image with a volume mount, e.g.:

```
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/adam/Desktop/Dev/ec2-data-analysis/grimlock",
            "Destination": "/opt/project",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
```

That volume mount overrides the contents of the image for that container. All access to the path will go to your desktop directory rather than the image contents, and Linux bind mounts do not have a concept of the `.dockerignore` file.

When you run this image without the volume mount, you should see different behavior.

---

For anyone coming across this question in the future, the `.dockerignore` needs to be in the root of your build context. The build context is the directory you pass at the end of the build command, often a `.` or the current directory. If you enable BuildKit, it will [first check for a `Dockerfile.dockerignore`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/releases/tag/dockerfile%2F1.1.0) where your Dockerfile path/name could be changed. And to test your `.dockerignore`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966234/596285).

Comment: Somehow its not working with the .dockerignore next to my Dockerfile. It copied all files from the context, as if the .dockerignore was never used.

Comment: @TheFool is that also the root of your build context? Did you verify by the linked test command and not by starting a container with volumes?

Comment: Yes, I just started the container and run ls. No volumes. I am using the latest docker version with buildx plugin. It's not at the root of the build context, but isn't that the whole point of that addition? Like, first look next to the Dockerfile and fallback to context root?

Comment: @TheFool I believe the new feature is `Dockerfile.dockerignore`, not `.dockerignore` , but I haven't tested it. Make sure you're on buildkit to use it, and if it still fails, that may be worth an issue on buildkit.

Comment: You are right. It needs to be `Dockerfile.dockerignore`. I misunderstood the release notes. Thank you.

Comment: for the `Dockerfile.dockerignore` to be taken into account, you need : `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build ...`

Comment: @IsmaelELATIFI buildkit has been enabled by default for a while now. If you don't see it without `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` set, you'll want to upgrade your install.