# The node_modules folder is not being ignored by .dockerignore when building Docker image

Tags: docker

I'm building a docker image and I have the node_modules folder included in the .dockerignore file. This is what my file looks like:

```
node_modules
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:20.6.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The node_modules is located directly in the directory I'm building the image from. I even tried adding Dockerfile to .dockerignore to make sure it wasn't my .dockerignore file that wasn't working but it worked fine and it did ignore Dockerfile.

I'm building my image using `docker build -t <image-tag> .`

Can somebody please point me to where I'm going wrong? No matter what I do, when I run the sh command using `docker run -it <image-id> sh` on my container, I see node_modules

Comment: How are you starting the container to verify its contents?  Does your image have something like a `RUN npm ci` or `RUN yarn install` command that would regenenerate the `node_modules` tree?

Comment: I edited the post to include the info you are asking for. I have `RUN npm install` after `COPY package.json .` and before `COPY . .` so that it can build the image using the cache if I make changes to the directory without adding any npm libraries.

Comment: Make sure that your file is really called `.dockerignore` - all small letters, starting with dot. Better retype the name (or `echo node_modules > .dockerignore` - I attest that spelling is correct here) and try again. Then explain what makes you think that `node_modules` is indeed copied from your fs - to check easily, `touch node_modules/test.txt`, build your image and check whether test.txt is there. If it is there, keep debugging. If not, go back to step 2 and explain better why you think it was copied.

Answer (score 0):

Could yo try this:

```
**/node_modules/
```

please.

Example of .dockerignore file (Best Practice):

```
**/node_modules/
**/dist
.git
npm-debug.log
.coverage
.coverage.*
.env
.aws
```

Comment: I just tried that and it did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: try this, please:
/node_modules

Comment: Also did not work

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your folder structure, please.

Comment: maybe this could be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713751/where-to-put-dockerignore