# How to list all files from the build context that affect the contents of the image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to list all files that get copied into the image from the build context, or affect the final contents of the image in any other way?

I need this for dependency tracking; I am sculpting a build system for a project that involves building multiple images and running containers from them in the local dev environment. I need this to be optimized for rapid code-build-debug cycle, and therefore I need to be able to avoid invoking `docker build` as tightly as possible. Knowing the exact set of files in the build context that end up affecting the image will allow me to specify those as tracked dependencies for the build step that invokes `docker build`, and avoid unnecessary rebuilds.

I don't need to have this filelist generated in advance, though that is prefereable. If no tool exists to generate it in advance, but there is a way to obtain it from a built image, then that's OK too; the build tool I use is capable of recording dynamic dependencies discovered by a post-build step.

Things that I am **acutely aware of**, and I **still make an informed decision** that pursuing this avenue is worthwile:

- I know that the number of dependencies thus tracked can be huge-ish. I believe the build tool can handle it.
- I know that there are other kinds of dependencies for a docker image besides files in the build context. This is solved by also tracking those dependencies outside of `docker build`. Unlike files from the build context, those dependencies are either much fewer in number (i.e. files that the Dockerfile's `RUN` commands explicitly fetch from the internet), or the problem of obtaining an exhaustive list of such dependencies is already solved (e.g. dependencies obtained using a package manager like `apt-get` are modeled separately, and the installing `RUN`s are generated into the Dockerfile from the model).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38946683/596285

Comment: The whole purpose is to obtain information that can be used to decide whether issuing `docker build` can be skipped. If obtaining this information requires issuing `docker build`, it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is copied to the image unless you specifically say so. So, check your Dockerfile for COPY statements and you will know what files from the build context are added to the image.

Notice that, in the event you have a `COPY . .`, you might have a `.dockerignore` file in the build context with files you don't want to copy.

Comment: That's precisely the problem: to obtain The Truth about the exact set of build context files that Docker actually did use to build the image, and to achieve this without parsing the Dockerfile and reimplementing docker's tree copying logic, the .dockerignore logic and possibly more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what's you're looking for would be useful even if it was possible. A list of all files in the previously built image wouldn't factor in new files, and it would be difficult to differentiate new files that affect the build from new files that would be ignored.

It's possible that you could parse the Dockerfile, extract every COPY and ADD command, run the current files through a hashing process to identify if they changed from the hash in the image history (you would need to match docker's hashing algorithm which includes details like file ownership and permissions), and then when that hash doesn't match you would know the build needs to run again. You could look at creating a custom buildkit syntax parser, or reuse the low level buildkit code to build your own context processor.

But before you spend too much time trying to implement the above code, realize that it already exists, as `docker build`. Rather than trying to avoid running a build, I'd focus on getting the build to utilize the build cache so new builds skip all unchanged steps, possibly generating the exact same image id.

Comment: Yes, I realize that `docker build` already exists. Even in the case of a 100% cached build, it does MUCH more work and is MUCH slower than determining whether even 100s of local files changed. Heck, my current solution based on git-stamping the entire build context is about 5 times faster than re-running `docker build` on unchanged context, even though my solution runs `git diff` over the entire monorepo. So PLEASE don't tell me that I am reinventing the wheel. Docker's "wheel" is square, I already invented a roughly octagonal one (a huge improvement), and I want a truly round one.

Comment: Of course my gitstamping solution doesn't handle .dockerignore, so it _does_ trigger spurious rebuilds if dockerignored files change. That's why I am looking for a TRUE solution.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski just to verify you are using buildkit and not pushing the result to an external registry?

Comment: Yes, I am using buildkit. Some build goals involve pushing images to external registry, some don't. In either case, skipping `docker build` yields measurable benefits. In a code-build-debug cycle, it often makes the difference between staying in the flow and dropping out of the flow.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski sounds like you've narrowed yourself into the second paragraph. Be sure when copying the hashing code to factor in the dockerignore file. I'd probably look to the buildkit repo for the Dockerfile parser to extract the copy and add commands. Once you have all that, you can compare the hashes to the previous image.