# How to get files not being .dockerignored when getting an unexpectedly large docker build context?

Tags: docker, dockerignore

I have a large monorepo that I'm using as a docker context. The src for the repo is only 250MB, but many of the sub-projects have .gitignored virtualenvs, npm_modules, etc.

It appears that one or many of these .gitignores didn't make it into .dockerignore, because I'm seeing 5GB of context being transmitted on my machine, which is both slow, and I want to debug what's missing from .dockerignore.

Is there a way to get a list of the files being sent as part of the docker context so I can debug what's in .gitignore that's missing from .dockerignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38946683/596285

Comment: It doesn't answer your question.. but `docker history <image-id>` shows the size of each layer, so you can see what's the command of your `Dockerfile` that could be doing this.

Comment: @BMitch agree its a dupe, thanks for finding this one and linking them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly that I know of, but indirectly it wouldn't be that hard.  You can `COPY` the entire build context into an image and then do whatever you want with that content.

```sh
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /stuff
# Just copy everything to the image
COPY . .
# Some default CMD is usually a good idea
CMD du -m | sort -n
```

```sh
# Build and run the image
docker build -t where-is-my-space -f Dockerfile.debug .
# The default `CMD` lists directories in the copied content
# sorted by size
docker run --rm where-is-my-space

# Huh, let's dig in more
docker run --rm where-is-my-space ls -l data/unexpected
# Or with an interactive shell (note, busybox doesn't have bash)
docker run --rm -it where-is-my-space sh

# All done, let's clean up
docker rmi where-is-my-space
```