# Location for common .dockerignore file

Tags: docker, dockerignore

I'd like a common `.dockerignore` file, "outside" a build context (which I assume is the directory in which the `Dockerfile` is located).

So instead of this:

```
project/
  client/
      src/
      .dockerignore
      Dockerfile
  server/
      src/
      .dockerignore
      Dockerfile
```

I prefer this:

```
project/
  client/
      src/
      Dockerfile
  server/
      src/
      Dockerfile
  .dockerignore
```

Is that allowed? Will it walk up the filesystem until root, looking for an ignore file (the way it's commonly done by other cli tools), or must it be at the same level as the Dockerfile?

There have been changes to the mechanism in recent docker versions, e.g. for custom `Dockerfile.foo.dockerignore` files, which must be placed at the same level as the `Dockerfile.foo`. So I'm unsure what is the current rule, and the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) don't explain.

I'm using the latest version, docker 24.0.5.

Comment: "which I assume is the directory in which the Dockerfile is located" that's a bad assumption. The build context is specified when you build the image.

Comment: "Will it walk up the filesystem until root" that's the sort of thing you can test yourself.

Comment: @BMitch How do you test such a thing?

Comment: You create a `.dockerignore` in a parent folder, run a build, and see if it works.

Comment: @BMitch How do you see if it works? How can you tell files were not sent to the builder unnecessarily?

Comment: Ignore a file you copy into the image and see if the file exists in the image.

Comment: @BMitch Ok I wasn't thinking of that.. I was so fixated on excluding files I didn't think of doing the reverse temporarily. And you gave a nice [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966234/9971404)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) link:

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named .dockerignore in the **root directory of the context**.

From [build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/):

> The build context is the argument that you pass to the build command. When your build context is a local directory, a remote Git repository, or a tar file, then that becomes the set of files that the builder can access during the build.

From [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files):

> By default the docker build command will look for a Dockerfile at the root of the build context. The -f, --file, option lets you specify the path to an alternative file to use instead.

So you should be able to do:

```
docker build -f client <path_to_project>
```

Something to keep in mind using this approach:
If you have only one .dockerignore file you wont be able to exclude the source code for the other builds. As a result the source code for **all** builds will be sent to the docker daemon in **each individual** build. So be careful that you are not sending large amounts of data.

Comment: Just what I was about to say!

Comment: Maybe someone who is more proficiant with docker than I am can add if this is a good idea to do.

Comment: From what I understand, that would need to be run from the project root, where the ignore file is located? It cannot be run in the directory of the dockerfile?

Comment: I believe this is the "usual" way to do it. You have the context at the level where the `.dockerignore` is, and then specify the path to the Dockerfiles in the build step. It's certainly how we do it where I work. The only downside is sending more data to the daemon for each build, which is only really an issue if you have large files that you are copying in (and then, you're probably doing it wrong)

Comment: @SiHa "sending more data to the daemon for each build" I don't understand - surely you'd just exclude unessential stuff in the ignore file?

Comment: @lonix Yes, you need to specify the path to the project root as build context (argument for the docker build command). As to SiHa's comment: If you have multiple Dockerfiles and one .dockerignore file you would send the files for all builds in each build process (= more data). In your case you would also send the server/src files when building the client Dockerfile.

Comment: In that case, what I wanted to do can be done (using your technically correct answer), but **shouldn't be done** - it's better to have separate ignore files at the same level as the separate dockerfiles, even if they are identical.

Comment: Depends on the size of your files and folders. If you just have your source code inside, it shouldnt be an issue.